# Specs2 strange behavior in custom matcher when combining beAnInstanceOf and "aka"

Tags: specs2

I'm experiencing strange behavior and I'm wondering if this is a bug or if I'm missing something.

The following code:

```
class Foo extends SpecificationWithJUnit {

  "This test should pass" in new ctx {
   Bar(Zoo("id")) must haveInstanceZoo
 }

 trait ctx extends Scope {

   def haveInstanceZoo : Matcher[Bar] = 
     beAnInstanceOf[Zoo] ^^ { (_: Bar).z aka "instanceOfZoo" }
 }
}

case class Bar(z: Zoo)
case class Zoo(id: String)
```

fails with the following Exception:

```
'org.specs2.matcher.ThrownExpectationsCreation$$anon$1@48072f8c: 
 org.specs2.matcher.ThrownExpectationsCreation$$anon$1' 
 is not an instance of 'com.test.Zoo'
```

If I remove the "aka" from the custom matcher everything works.

Thoughts?

Thanks
Netta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `aka` like this because you are effectively trying to assert that an `Expectation`, the object you create with `aka` is an instance of `Zoo`.

If you want to specify a different failure message on a matcher you can write this:

```
def haveInstanceZoo: Matcher[Bar] = (bar: Bar) =>
  (bar.z.isInstanceOf[Zoo], "bar.z is not an instance of Zoo")
```

Comment: why does it work for something like: 
    def beAZoo : Matcher[Zoo] = be_==("id") ^^ { ( _: Zoo).id aka "id"}?

Comment: This works only if you use `be_===` because in that case the type of the `^^` parameter can drive the selection of an overloaded `^^` method accepting an `Expectable[Zoo]` (which is returned by `aka`).